# Creating a static smoke, saving it and making it interactable

Tags: smoke-simulation, baking, point-clouds

I've created a smoke simulation using quick smoke, I adjusted the values to my liking and ran the sim. (plane of smoke with a collider cube piercing it and the smoke being moved by the cube.) The sim runs about 250 frames and I saved and baked the smoke. What I don't know and cant seem to find any info on is
 how to save the frame 200 where the smoke looks the best, stop it from continuing the simulation, and use that smoke as a different object in another scene. Basically creating Cumulonimbus cloud,  like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2s15.jpg Then I'd like to have the cloud be interactable again as a smoke cloud with a plane flying through it. If anyone can help with how I can achieve this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you would just need to copy your scene. Then you would have to re bake and change the collision object to the plane. Basically I think you would need 2 different smoke sims.

Comment: Can you clarify that a little?

Comment: well, once you bake something, you can no longer make changes to it or add any object for it to interact with. So if you have another scene that you want a plane to fly through you would have to make a second smoke sim. Since you like the one you have already, you can copy the domian object and flow object and paste it into your plane scene. You then would have to clear the bake and rebake in your new scene. I dont know of a way to "freeze" the smoke and then have an object interact with it after its frozen.

Comment: I've done similar but had to compromise, freeze the smoke as an alpha layered image and use that to texture a transparent plane in the second scenario.  The textured plane was distorted using keyframes and shape keys to emulate cloud reaction as the object went through it.  I can upload a similar project or it's gif anim if you're not insisting on volumetric.

Comment: Further to the comment above, I also use multiple planes to emulate volumetric.

Comment: I would still love to see this because I like the simplicity. And would be useful for something quick vs volumetrics particle interactions, btw it's still rendering....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution I was looking for and thanks for the tip about baking. I'll post the link to what solved my problem. https://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quicktip-store-a-single-frame-from-your-blender-25-smoke-sim--cg-5366

Comment: Glad you found something. Keep in mind its just a single frame. So it wont move when the plane goes through the cloud.

Comment: I'm going to try overlaying another smoke sim as you suggested inside the single frame so it creates that jutting motion of air particles without destroying the original cloud shape it'll probably turn out better than I had anticipated because of both solutions.